# Why does `fmap sum Just` typecheck?

Tags: haskell, functor, foldable

We know `fmap` is `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` and `sum` is `sum :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a`, but the code below confuse me.

```
> :t (fmap sum Just)
(fmap sum Just) :: Num b => b -> b
> fmap sum Just 3
3
```

why?

Comment: I'm sure, you can try [it](https://www.tryhaskell.org/).

Comment: Yep, I realised `sum` comes from `Data.Foldable`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there are probably two confusing bits here.

The first, most obvious, is that `sum` works on `Foldable` things, not just lists.  Therefore:

```
sum (Just 3) == 3
```

The second is the functor instance you are using.  Since `Just` is a function, as that is the second argument to `fmap`, you are using the reader instance of fmap, which is defined here (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-638) as simply `(.)`.

It looks weird, and like it shouldn't type-check, because you are supplying three arguments to fmap, but actually, the result of the (fmap sum Just) is a function:

```
Prelude> :t fmap sum Just
fmap sum Just :: Num b => b -> b
```

If we replace `fmap` with `.`, things start to make a little more sense.

```
Prelude> (.) sum Just 3
3

Prelude> (sum . Just) 3
3
```

Which is the same as

```
sum (Just 3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm haskell newbie. I haven't learned reader instance, but I think you're right. I will check it later.

Comment: You're welcome.  This instance usually shows up as `((->) r)` in most cases, and it can be easy to miss what's going on when this shows up somewhere, simply because functions feel like they should act somehow special, but in Haskell it's a type like everything else so it's much more consistent than other languages.